# Not able to plot Open Data Cube dataset image

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, open-data-cube

I'm trying to plot the indexed Open Data Cube dataset image through the Jupyter Notebook. I'm using [this demo notebook](https://github.com/opendatacube/datacube-notebooks/blob/master/Demo_Notebook.ipynb) after making a clone of [this repository](https://github.com/opendatacube/datacube-notebooks) on my local machine.
The `plot()` method as shown below is not showing any image on output.

```
import datacube
dc = datacube.Datacube(app = 'my_app', config = 'C:/Users/user/datacube.conf')
ds = dc.load(product='LISS3_test1',
        longitude=(85.75, 86),
        latitude=(20.25, 20.5),
        output_crs='EPSG:4326',
        resolution=(-0.000225, 0.000225)
)
nir_image = ds.nir
nir_image.plot(cmap = "Greys")
```

The only output is `<matplotlib.collections.QuadMesh at 0x364bf59e88>` without any image.

`type(nir_image)` command gives `xarray.core.dataarray.DataArray` as output.

`print(ds.nir)` command gives following output,

```
<xarray.DataArray 'nir' (time: 1, latitude: 1112, longitude: 1112)>
array([[[82, 77, 78, ..., 81, 76, 73],
        [82, 76, 72, ..., 77, 77, 75],
        [87, 78, 72, ..., 75, 77, 79],
        ...,
        [85, 84, 82, ..., 69, 68, 71],
        [83, 80, 76, ..., 71, 74, 73],
        [79, 78, 79, ..., 71, 74, 77]]], dtype=uint8)
Coordinates:
  * time         (time) datetime64[ns] 2021-07-23T14:30:54.147622
  * latitude     (latitude) float64 20.5 20.5 20.5 20.5 ... 20.25 20.25 20.25
  * longitude    (longitude) float64 85.75 85.75 85.75 85.75 ... 86.0 86.0 86.0
    spatial_ref  int32 4326
Attributes:
    units:         1
    nodata:        0
    crs:           EPSG:4326
    grid_mapping:  spatial_ref
```

**Can anyone please say what's wrong here and how to plot any particular band image in the notebook?**

I am doing a local installation of Open Data Cube and indexed some datasets with PostgreSQL on a Windows 8.1 system.

*Edit - 1 ------------------------------------------------------------------*

What I understood from other example notebooks is, the `nir_image` is 3 dimensional data with time being the 3rd dimension. So I did manage to plot with the following code.

```
nir_image = ds.nir.isel(time=0)
nir_image.plot(cmap="gray")
```

This code displayed the image, but when I closed the system and open again, no image is being displayed. only `<matplotlib.collections.QuadMesh at 0x170bcc5c48>` is in the output.

**What is the problem here? Why is it showing only some of the times?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might be able to be solved just by running `plt.show()` after calling the `.plot()` method.

Another issue I have sometimes encountered is importing matplotlib and then plotting something in the same cell in Jupyter Notebooks. I can't remember why this issue was caused or if it fixed now, but perhaps the following will work (with the imports in a different cell):

```
import datacube
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

```
dc = datacube.Datacube(app = 'my_app', config = 'C:/Users/user/datacube.conf')
ds = dc.load(product='LISS3_test1',
        longitude=(85.75, 86),
        latitude=(20.25, 20.5),
        output_crs='EPSG:4326',
        resolution=(-0.000225, 0.000225)
)
nir_image = ds.nir
nir_image.plot(cmap = "Greys")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Jupyter Notebooks may need the matplotlib enable magic before it starts showing the output in a cell.

This is called the matplotlib inline backend.

Something like this in a cell should tell you if this is working.

```
%matplotlib inline

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 3*np.pi, 500)
plt.plot(x, np.sin(x**2))
plt.title('A simple chirp');
```

See more details here : https://github.com/ipython/matplotlib-inline

Comment: This didn't solve my issue. With this, the image comes as some sort of line plot but I needed it to display the image. I managed to display the image as I have mentioned in the edit. But now again it's not showing.